# Parsing substring in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to parse a substring with specific pattern in Python.

Eg:

```
[ AA BB ] (CC) DD "String to extract"

"Another string in Next line"

XX "Another string"
```

I would like to extract the string in quotes from lines that begin with `[`. I don't need all strings within quotes. How do I do this in Python?

Comment: Use "Regular Expression" (RegEx)

Comment: what strings do you want ?

Comment: I would like to extract only "String to extract" from line1 as that line begins with a "["

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where your lines are coming from but if each line is different.

```
import re
lines=['[ AA BB ] (CC) DD "String to extract"',"Another string in Next line",'XX "Another string"']
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("["):
        print re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',line)
['String to extract']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your source iterable...

```
myStrings = []
for line in some_iterable:
    if line.startswith('['):
        myStrings.append(line.split('"')[1]
```

OR

```
myStrings = [l.split('"')[1] for l in some_iterable if l.startswith('[')]
```